# How to achieve results without repeating code?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to prompt a question formatted exactly like this:

```
      What is your favourite programming language?
      0: JavaScript
      1: Python
      2: Rust
      3: C++
```

I achieved this by destructuring the `options` array inside the `poll` object inside the `resisterNewAnswer()` method. I used the `\n` but looks horrible repeating it. I tried using a for of loop but not sure how to implement it. I'm trying to achieve this inside the  `resisterNewAnswer()` method.

```js
const poll = {
  question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
  options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3:c++'],
  answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    const [j, p, r, c] = this.options;
    prompt(
      `What is your favourite programming language? \n ${j} \n ${p} \n ${r} \n ${c}`
    );
  },
};
poll.registerNewAnswer();
```

Comment: `this.options.join('\n ')`, or whatever, to get a single string with all the parts joined together

Comment: What you have already is pretty spot on...

Comment: i finally understand what you want.. you want SEVERAL results right? i put an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use any one of the popular JavaScript templating libraries: [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs), [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) or [mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache).

Here is an example using mustache:

```js
const questionTemplate = `\
{{question}}
{{#options}}
{{index}}: {{option}}
{{/options}}
`;

const poll = {
  question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
  options: ['JavaScript', 'Python', 'Rust', 'C++'],
  answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    prompt(Mustache.render(questionTemplate, {
      question: this.question,
      options: this.options.map((option, index) => ({option, index})),
    }));
  },
};
poll.registerNewAnswer();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@4/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

The `\` behind the initial `` ` `` is to ignore the first newline character.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would do is use `this.question` in the prompt instead of repeating it. Also combining the options using join will allow you to simplify while having the ability to use different number of options.

```js
const poll = {
  question: '',
  options: [],
  answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    return prompt(`${this.question}\n${this.options.join("\n")}`
    );
  },
};

poll.question = "What is your favorite programming language?";
poll.options = ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3:c++'];
console.log(poll.registerNewAnswer());

poll.question = "Question 2?";
poll.options = ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3:c++'];
console.log(poll.registerNewAnswer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `join` method to achieve this:

```js
const poll = {
  question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
  options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3: C++'],
  answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    const [j, p, r, c] = this.options;
    prompt(
      `What is your favourite programming language?\n${this.options.join('\n')}`
    );
  },
};
poll.registerNewAnswer();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const poll = {
  question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
  options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3: c++'],
  answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    const jprc=`\n${this.options.join('\n')}`
    const x=()=>prompt(`What is your favourite programming language? ${jprc}\nOr -1 to end entries`) //x becomes a function that prompts you and returns what you input
    var i=x()
    while(i!=-1){this.answers[i%this.options.length]++;i=x()} //the % logic to prevent incorrect entry(or you can have an if statement that just won't record it if incorrect index)
  },
};
poll.registerNewAnswer();
console.log(poll.answers)
```